# Unable to create new Project in GCP. Cloud Service disabled by admin. Please contact admin to restore service

Tags: google-cloud-platform

anyone can help? i try to create my first Google Project, and i got this error

Create Project: My Project

APPHOSTING_ADMIN Cloud Service disabled by admin. Please contact admin to restore service. com.google.apps.framework.request.StatusException: generic::FAILED_PRECONDITION: APPHOSTING_ADMIN Cloud Service disabled by admin. Please contact admin to restore service

anyone any idea?

i am the admin from the GSuite account. I had checked my permission stuff in my account and i don't think there is a place for me to disable me from using GCP.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason for such error message would be the disabled G-Suite access to the `Google Developers Console` service.

Check in your [GSuite Admin console](https://admin.google.com) `Apps` -> `Additional Google services` if `Google Developers Console` is enabled:

[image]

If it's not - enable it and re-try